# PHP is displayed to page because Doctype = Strict

Tags: php, html, doctype

I am working on a Contact Form in my .php file. I have always worked with loose doctypes, however, today I am using strict. I have my php above my html, and none of the code runs. Instead, it just displays some of the Echos to the page (these aren't even called yet). Also, in my form, I have the following:

```
<INPUT NAME="Name" SIZE="30" value="<?php echo $Name; ?>">
```

On the page inside the field, it is displaying: `<?php echo $Name; ?>`

What is going on here and how can I fix this issue?

Yes, the pages are .php
Here is the doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Any input appreciated

Comment: The doctype shouldn't affect whether the PHP is interpreted, this is likely a problem with your web server configuration. Try changing the doc type to something absurd and see if the problem still persists.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but that is also invalid XHTML. Element and attribute names should be in lowercase and empty elements need to end in `/>`.

Comment: I agree with @Stefan - it's most likely a server configuration issue.  Try the simplest php page:  a file containing only `<?php phpinfo();`. Make sure that works first, then come back and check this issue again.

Answer (score 2):

If raw PHP code is output to the browser, it means the PHP wasn't processed on the server. It has nothing to do with the doctype, the server doesn't care about the doctype. There's a configuration problem on the server that causes it to serve .php files as-is, without pushing them through the PHP pre-processor. That, or you're accessing the file directly like `file:///path/to/file.php`, instead of requesting it through a web server.